# Segmentation fault after converting char[] to char*[]

Tags: arrays, c, char

```
void allocate(char string[])
{
    int nrCuv = 0, init_sz = strlen(string), counter = 0;
    char delim[] = "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)      //Here I calculated the number of words from the file
    {
        if (string[i] == "\n")
        {
            nrCuv += 1;
        }
    }

    nrCuv += 1;
    char *tablou[nrCuv];

    char *ptr = strtok(string, delim);
    while (ptr != NULL)                 //Here I tried to split the initial char into words
    {
        tablou[counter] = ptr;
        // printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        counter += 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nrCuv; i++)
    {
        puts(tablou[i]);
    }

}
```

The variable `string` has the contents of a file that has one word per line. I was trying to format the string variable so that I can access every word from within the `tablou` variable, like this

`tablou[1] = "foo"`

`tablou[2] = "bar"`

For some reason that I don't understand. it doesn't seem to work properly at all. Sometimes I get Segmenation Faults, sometimes it only prints the first word of the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, in the loop that calls `puts`, it would be better to use `i < counter` as the terminating condition because `counter` might be less than `nrCuv` and only `counter` pointers have been set in `tablou[]`.

Comment: @JonGuiton This is C99's (and on) variable sized array, it is legal though limited (to the stack).

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: `string[i] == "\n"` -> `string[i] == '\n'`, didn't you get at least a compiler warning? Othwerwise I don't see any obvious problems in your code. The problem most likely is in the calling code. See my previous comment and comply.

Comment: it worked changing `string[i] == "\n"` to `string[i] == '\n'`, though I got no errors/ warnings from the compiler

Comment: What compiler do you have ? Be aware that `allocate("foo\nbar")` won't work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I use gcc 9.3.0 . Indeed, `allocate("foo\nbar")` does not work. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @FusiFlag you cannot modify string literals. The alternative would be to make a copy of the string. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a